# frontName = page name?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, frontend, configuration, router

In this [config.xml](https://github.com/adyenpayments/plugins/blob/master/magento/app/code/community/Madia/Adyen/etc/config.xml) of module I am using there is a frontName defined as `adyen`:

```
    <routers>
        <adyen>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Madia_Adyen</module>
                <frontName>adyen</frontName>
            </args>
        </adyen>
    </routers>
```

But if I open `http://myshop.com/adyen/` there is no page. In another module I have a similar definition for another `frontName` and it works fine there.

Why does it work the same way here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of front name as an alias for module controller directory (that's what it is!). The reason the other module works with just a front name is likely because it has an `IndexController` with an `indexAction()`. If you did the same in your `adyan` module then you could use the front-name-only URL as well.

Answer (score 3):

`adyen` is only the first part of the url. complete url is `http://myshop.com/frontName/controller/function`

So in this case `http://myshop.com/adyen/process/soap` will call `Madia_Adyen_ProcessController::soapAction()`